# Can Four Square Provide The SF Of The Business Searched?

Tags: api, size, building

Even though the building size/square footage doesn't hold much value to foursquare users; as a company looking to use Four square's  API is it possible to obtain the size/square footage of the business that users search?

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot display the square footage, unless for some reason that was posted in the description of the venue or venue name itself.